# sails.js waterline query result from multiple table in database

Tags: javascript, database, post, controller, sails.js

I have a database with two tables: 'GroupTable' & 'ItemTable'. GroupTable stores the group information such as group name etc. The ItemTable stores the item information as well as which group they belong to. Here's the thing, i am not using foreign key for some reason which i will not explain.
GroupTable: id, name, code
ItemTable: id, name, code, group

The ItemTable also stores the group, differentiated by group='-1'. So what i did was: Find all items in ItemTable with 'group = -1', get the codes of all the items, then filter the GroupTable and find all groups that has codes from the result. Because i need the group names of those groups which are in the ItemTable.

```
var grp = -1;
$.post("ItemTable/getItems", {group:grp}, function(result){
  if(!result.error){
    var count = result.data.length;
    var data = result.data
    var codes = new Array;
    for (var i=0; i<count; i++) {
      groups.push(data[i].code);
    }
    $.post("GroupTable/getItem", {code:codes}, function(result2) {
      if (!result2.error){
        var grpCount = result2.data.length;
        var grpData = result2.data;
        for (var i=0; i<grpCount; i++){
          var name = grpData[i].name;
          //DO SOMETHING WITH THE NAME HERE
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there anyway i can achieve the same result using only a single post? Or am i looking at this wrongly and i should be editing my getItems function in my controller instead? Currently i am using 'TableItem.find(queryItem).exec()', how should i be writing my code to fit what i am trying to achiveve?

And yes let's assume for some reason i am not able to use foreign key, and that my code will ensure the 'code' is unique in GroupTable.

EDIT:
I am unable to copy and paste as i am working in an offline environment. I am using a MVC model, the code above are the codes for my view. As for the function 'getItems' in my controller, this is the code in my controller(summarized as i have to type this out)

```
getItems: function(req, res){
 var id, name;
 (typeof(req.params.id) === 'undefined') ? id=req.body.id : id=req.params.id;
 (typeof(req.params.name) === 'undefined') ? name=req.body.name : name=req.params.name;

var queryItem = {
  id: id,
  name: name
};
// there is more than just id and name, as i did not type everything out
for (var propertyName in queryItem) {
 if (queryItem[propertyName] == null){
  delete queryItem[propertyName];
 }
}

ItemTable.find(queryItem).exec(function(err, items){
 if (err)
  red.json({"error":err, data:null});
 else
  res.json({"error":null, data: items});
});
```

Comment: Is your code above part of a controller action? $.post looks unfamiliar to me.

Comment: Paste ur controller functions and name of each file which ur using while  this operation, pls.